# Unable to connect to AWS EC2 instance (Permission denied publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am trying to connect to an EC2 instance which I recently spun up via the following SSH command from my Mac OS:

```
ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/mykey.pem ec2-***.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I have removed the exact DNS name as it is probably not relevant here.  Before I attempted to connect, I took the following steps:

- Added a rule for inbound SSH traffic (using my IP)
- Created an SSH key in AWS *before* spinning up the instance
- Placed the private key `mykey.pem` file in my user `.ssh` folder

I have read many SO questions and other documentation, which is why I was even able to put the above steps together.  I am at a loss as to why I can't connect to my EC2 instance, but I am hoping someone will see a flaw in what I am doing here.

Comment: Can you share the complete error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the user name:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/key.pem ec2-user@host-or-ip
```

Depending on the type of instance, that user name may be ec2-user (amazon linux) or ubuntu (ubuntu).  Other versions may have different requirements (some older redhat instances still use root, for example), but that should cover most cases.

Comment: Spot on answer +1. Funny thing is that yesterday I _didn't_ make this mistake, but did have a problem with the keys.  I fixed that, but in my laziness forgot the username this time around.